# Retrieve country for OSM elements

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I'm using overpass to retrieve information about OSM ways around some coordinates.

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
way["highway"](around:100,49.8385,24.0199);
out meta;
```

The default `meta` output is not sufficient for me -- I need to have *city*, *country* etc for every returned object.

I have two ideas on how to solve it:

1. Use recursion up (`<`) to traverse all the objects up
2. Use `is_in` query inside a `foreach` command for each object

I'm having problems with syntax / implementation on Overpass QL for both the ways.

My code for #1: (https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/NUi)

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
(way["highway"](around:100,49.8385,24.0199);
<;
);
out meta;
```

The result looks like recursion isn't applied.

My code for #2: (https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/NUj)

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
way["highway"](around:10,49.8385,24.0199);
foreach(is_in; out;)
```

Could you please point me on what is wrong here?

Comment: `is_in` only works with nodes, not with ways as in your second example. The first approach will not work at all, because there's no relation to recurse to from a given way (the way is most likely not a member of a city or country relation).

Comment: thanks, @mmd do you please see any other solutions to this?